# Fedena Image in PDF Report using wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fedena

I am trying to insert image in student report, edited the below code and it shows the default image but when I upload the student image it doesn't show it.

```
<% if @student.photo.file? %>
        <%= wicked_pdf_image_tag @student.photo.url %>
      <% else %>
        <%= wicked_pdf_image_tag "master_student/profile/default_student.png" %>
      <% end %>
```

Comment: <%= @student.photo.url %> is showing the correct path to the image but not showing in pdf report.

Comment: the actual path to the image file is: /uploads/students/photos/000/000/original/002/abc.jpg